# Преобразование матрицы в excel в 2 столбеца формулой

Tags: excel, матрицы

Помогите пожалуйста в решении следующей задачи. В ячейках A2:F4 имеется массив (матрица) с четным количеством столбцов. Нужно сделать из него два столбца, чтобы 2 соседние ячейки строки оказались в разных столбцах. В ячейки G2:H10 ввожу формулу массива

```
={СМЕЩ(матрица;(СТРОКА()-СТРОКА($G$2))/(ЧИСЛСТОЛБ(матрица)/2);(ОСТАТ((СТРОКА()-СТРОКА($G$2));(ЧИСЛСТОЛБ(матрица)/2))*2);1;2)}
```

В результате получаю #ЗНАЧ! Что я делаю не так. Почему формула `={СМЕЩ(матрица;0;2;1;2)}` работает если вводить её в две соседние ячейки, а та что выше не работает? Если делать два вспомогательных  столбца для расчета смещения по строкам/столбцам, то формула тоже работает, но хочется обойтись без вспомогательных столбцов

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Несколько смущает фигурная скобка после знака равенства - у Вас это выглядит именно так? Или это просто опечатка? Мне Ваша формула выдала все 18 значений в нужном порядке, 9 строк по две ячейки

Answer (score 0):

фигурная скобка означает что введена формула массива, появляется автоматически после нажатия клавиш Ctrl+Shift+Enter[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну да, опечатка, не `={`, а `{=`

Answer (score 0):

Фигурные скобки - признак формулы массива. Но это не все... Формулы массива могут возвращать одно значение или массив значений. Формулы массива вводятся двумя способами - в одну ячейку или в диапазон ячеек. Функцией `СМЕЩ` можно смещаться относительно ячейки или относительно диапазона.

Имеем матрицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеем короткую формулу :

```
=СМЕЩ(A2;0;2)
```

Сместиться относительно `A2` на 0 строк (без смещения по строкам), 2 столбца. Результат - значение ячейки `C2`

```
=СМЕЩ(A2;0;2;1;2)
```

Из предыдущего примера знаем, что получаем ссылку на `C2`, но теперь добавился размер диапазона - 1 строка, 2 столбца: `C2:D2`. Если формулу пересчитать (выделить ее в строке формул и нажать `F9`), увидим возвращаемый массив, состоящий из значений диапазона:

```
={3;4}
```

Вот и подошли к формулам массива.

В одной ячейке не может храниться больше одного  значения. Формула может возвратить массив значений, но отображаться будет только одно  (*для данного примера - из верхней левой ячейки диапазона, но в формулах сложнее это может быть любое значение диапазона, зависит от применяемых функций*)

Если ввести последнюю формулу в одну ячейку, то будет отображено только значение из `C2`. И неважно, введена формула как массивная или как обычная.

Но если выделить две ячейки в строке, вписать формулу в строку формул и завершить ввод формулы `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, получим результат - массив значений, возвращаемый формулой, распределится по ячейкам. Естественно, для массива другого размера количество выделенных ячеек должно быть другим.

С диапазоном почти так же, но смещается ссылка  на диапазон, а не на ячейку.

```
=СМЕЩ(матрица;0;2;1;2)
```

Для указанной матрицы исходные ссылки: `A2:F4`. Сместились на 0 строк, 2 столбца - получили диапазон `C2:H4`. Это если не указан размер диапазона.  Но формула говорит, что нужно из полученного диапазона взять 2 ячейки в 1 строке. Отсчет ведется от верхней левой ячейки, результат - все те же `C2:D2`, другие ссылки игнорируются.

Для закрепления полученной информации предлагаю самостоятельно разобраться, как работает формула из заглавного сообщения :)

---

Есть решение задачи намного проще, с применением обычных формул (без массивного ввода). Да и функция `СМЕЩ` летуча (пересчитывается при любых изменениях на листе). Если есть замена - `СМЕЩ` лучше не использовать:

```
=ИНДЕКС(матрица;СТРОКА(A1)/3,01+1;ОКРУГЛ(ОСТАТ(СТРОКА(A1);3,01);)*2-1)
=ИНДЕКС(матрица;СТРОКА(A1)/3,01+1;ОКРУГЛ(ОСТАТ(СТРОКА(A1);3,01);)*2)
```

Две формулы для двух столбцов, различие только в определении столбца (-1 есть/нет)

Для применения с матрицами разного размера 3 (тройку) заменить на `ЧИСЛСТОЛБ(матрица)/2` или счет значений в одной строке. Еще лучше - заменить на ссылки на ячейку, в которой высчитывается нужное значение